# How to change SharePoint 2010 local site used for debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint 2010 project that was created with a local site that is no longer a SharePoint site because the port number was required for another application.  However, another local site is available for SharePoint development.

Where is the local site setting stored, so that I can change the port?  I can't find it in the .csproj file or any of the other project (and solution) files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Highlight the project you are working on within the **Solution Explorer** and update the **SiteURL** property to reflect the local site you would like to use.

Comment: Thanks!  That's nice and easy, although it's also nice to know where the setting is physically stored.

Comment: I spent too long looking for this... Searching inside csproj and other xml files... Thanks! By the way, where are these properties stored? Shouldn't they be in the csproj file (or vbproj)?! I looked there...

Answer (score 0):

Despite looking for a long time, somehow I knew I'd find the answer as soon as I asked the question.  The setting is in the .csproj.user file.  Lesson: don't trust Visual Studio "Find In Files".